# Mask R-CNN and Extract Object

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm new in Image Processing .I am trying to extract persons in a photos and i want to move objects to another background.I used Mask RCNN.This can detect object and make instance segmentation but i don't make how to crop the finding objects.

I find a code extract the objects but this code extract just last element.

I will wait your answers...

```
# Visualize results
r = results[0]


visualize.display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'], class_names, r['scores'])


def segment(image,scores,masks):
    idx = scores.argmax()
    mask = masks[:,:,idx]
    mask = np.stack((mask,)*3,axis = -1)
    mask = mask.astype('uint8')
    bg = 255-mask*255
    mask_img = image*mask
    result = mask_img+bg
    display_images(result)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code is extracting the mask which has the best score (not the last element). To get all masks in RGB you can use something like this :

```
def get_rgb_masks(scores,masks):
    masks_rgb = []
    for i, s in enumerate(scores):
        idx = scores.argmax()
        mask = masks[:,:,idx]
        mask = np.stack((mask,)*3,axis = -1)
        mask = mask.astype('uint8')
        masks_rgb.append(mask)
    return masks_rgb
```

But in your case, I think the better option is to use "paste" function from PIL with mask -> https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-paste/ (read the section "Use mask image").